# R: How to drop columns with less than 10% 1's

Tags: r

My dataset:

```
a b c
1 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
```

I want to drop columns which have less than 10% 1's. I have this code but it's not working:

```
sapply(df, function(x) df[df[,c(x)]==1]>0.1))
```

Maybe I need a totally different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this option with `apply()` and a build-in function to test the threshold of 1 across each column. I have created a dummy example. The index `i` contains the columns that will be dropped after using `myfun` to compute the proportion of 1's in each column. Here the code:

```
#Data
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,0),20,10))
df$V1<-c(1,rep(0,19))
df$V2<-c(1,rep(0,19))
#Function
myfun <- function(x) {sum(x==1)/length(x)}
#Index For removing
i <- unname(which(apply(df,2,myfun)<0.1))
#Drop
df2 <- df[,-i]
```

The output:

```
df2
   V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3   1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
5   1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
7   1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
8   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
9   1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
11  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
12  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
13  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
14  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
15  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
16  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
17  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
18  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
19  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

Where columns `V1` and `V2` are dropped due to having 1's less than 0.1.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colMeans` in base R to keep columns that have more than 10% of 1's.

```
df[colMeans(df == 1) >= 0.1, ]
```

Or in `dplyr` use `select` with `where` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(where(~mean(. == 1) >= 0.1))
```